# Why is the same http post request failing with jsoup but working with AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, http, networking, jsoup, asynchttpclient

want to get the data from reddit profile pages. Some of these pages are tagged as nsfw, so users have to click accept in gui. (e.g. https://old.reddit.com/user/3DigitIQ) After clicking the page send a post request with "over18=yes" body and gets redirected to get request.

Now I want to rebuild this request in jsoup. the first request is allways getting redirected to reddit startpage. The second AsyncHttpClient request works fine and redirects correctly to https://old.reddit.com/user/3DigitIQ . I think its the same request. So one of these libaries is doing something in the background I dont understand. Someone knows whats the difference?

```
        String url2 = " https://old.reddit.com/over18?dest=https://old.reddit.com/user/3DigitIQ";
        String res = Jsoup.connect(url2)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
            .requestBody("over18=yes")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute()
            .body();

    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(res).select("title").text());
    // REDIRECT TO REDDIT MAIN PAGE

    AsyncHttpClient client = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
    String newPageBody = client.prepare("POST", url2)
            .setBody("over18=yes")
            .setFollowRedirect(true)
            .execute()
            .get()
            .getResponseBody();

    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(newPageBody).select("title").text());
    // REDIRECT TO EXPECTED REDDIT USER PAGE
```